# How to get number from json and add Flask-WTForms fields accordingly

Tags: python, json, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm building an object detection app. It detects planes in a given image and writes the coordinates in a dictionary:

```
    planes = 
{'Plane 1': {'Plane Coordinates': [20.0, 20.0, 551.0, 52.0], 'Plane Type': 1, 'Points': [2]}, 
'Plane 2': {'Plane Coordinates': [502.0, 425.0, 741.0, 713.0], 'Plane Type': 7, 'Points': [2]}, 
'Plane 3': {'Plane Coordinates': [55.0, 669.0, 310.0, 736.0], 'Plane Type': 2, 'Points': [2]}, 
'Plane 4': {'Plane Coordinates': [503.0, 1194.0, 805.0, 1222.0], 'Plane Type': 5, 'Points': []}, 
'Plane 5': {'Plane Coordinates': [56.0, 1240.0, 391.0, 1268.0], 'Plane Type': 8, 'Points': []}}
```

**But here's the tricky part:**

I want users to add values to  `Points` key. So when detection completes, I want to create a form where people can add points to detected planes.

I decided to use Flask WTForms *(but I can change it according to recommendations, maybe I could use JS?)* I just don't know how to duplicate the same field according to the detected number of planes.

So I came up with a solution like this:

I save the dictionary as a JSON file. And then in `forms.py` I open that with this code:

```
json_file_path = "planes.json"

with open(json_file_path, 'r') as j:
     contents = json.loads(j.read())
```

And try this:

```
class PlanesValue(Form):
for key in contents:
    plane = FieldList(StringField(key), min_entries=1)
submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

But the problem is it just renders the last `Plane` which is `Plane 5` as the only field.

I can understand that since it loops over the keys in contents it just come up with the last item in the dictionary, I don't know how to solve this problem.

Also I don't know how to add those values one by one to the `planes` dictionary above on form validation :/

I would be grateful for any help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
What I want to achieve:
Instead of 'static field' here, I want Flask WTForms to look at the `planes` dictionary, fetch the labels and generate : 'Plane 1, Plane 2, Plane 3, Plane 4, Plane 5'
[image]

Comment: Can you explain better what you re trying to achieve? Try and give a step by step, minimalistic example. What do you mean by "duplicate the same field according to the detected nb of planes"? Also, you can access the list of points and add to it by doing `planes['Plane 1']['Points'].append(3)`

Comment: Thank you, I've edited the original post and added what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're having trouble with, I think I am doing the same thing in my own application. In your Python event processor you need to add an instance of your 'plane' field based on some event. Here I am doing that with something I call 'filter'.

Here is a portion of my form (I've simplified a bit from my actual application)...

```
class QueryDefFormRow(FlaskForm):
    tbl_col_name = SelectField(label='Column', render_kw={'title': "Column to filter on",'class': "form-control"})
    operator = SelectField(label='Operator', render_kw={'title': "Operation to perform",'class': "form-control"},
                           choices=[('=', '='), ('<', '<'), ('<=', '<='), ('>', '>'), ('>=', '>=')])
    value = StringField(label='Value', render_kw={'title': 'Value to filter against.','class': "form-control"})
    btn_delete = ImageButtonField(label='Delete',render_kw={'class': "btn btn-dark", 'title': 'Remove this filter', 'image_class':"fas fa-trash fa-sm"})

class QueryDefForm(FlaskForm):
    qry_def = FieldList(unbound_field=FormField(form_class=QueryDefFormRow))
    btn_add_filter = SubmitField(label='Add Filter', render_kw={'class': "btn btn-primary btn-fill btn-space",
                                                                'title': 'Add another filter'})
```

And here is the Python where I process clicks on btn_add_filter...

```
if form.btn_add_filter.data:  # User pressed the add row button
    form.qry_def.append_entry()
```

As you can see, when the user hits the add filter button, I add another filter row. **That append_entry() method might be the key part that you need.** The result looks like this on the screen...

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your precious answer, but I solved with my own method for now although it was an ugly way. I'll put a pin on what you described and return an answer when I try again.

Comment: Great! You can also post your own answer and mark it as the correct one if you think it's best.